# problem in mirroring interfaces' traffic using OVS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, traffic, openstack, tap

I'm trying to mirror all incoming/outgoing traffic of an interface "eth0" on VM04, to another interface "eth1" on VM01, using open Vswtich  integrated with neutron in openstack.
Both VMs are in one subnet , using ubuntu and promisc mode is enabled on compute and VMs.

[This](http://paste.openstack.org/show/481122/) is the output of "ovs-vsctl show" command on my compute node.

I entered following command:

> ovs-vsctl -- set Bridge br-int mirrors=@m \
>
> -- --id=@vif4.0 get Port qvocb9f960c-fa \
>
> -- --id=@vif1.0 get Port qvo7b814729-7e \
>
> -- --id=@m create Mirror name=mirror1 \
>   select-dst-port=@vif4.0 \
>   select-src-port=@vif4.0 \
>   output-port=@vif1.0

after that, on my compute node, I can see all traffics using tcpdump command, but on VM01, I can just see "request" traffic; not "responds":

[image]

I don't know why and how can I fix it to mirror all traffics.

Thanks in advance!